# Issue Connecting AWS Amplify to Flutter App

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am trying to connect my AWS amplify data model to my flutter app and have followed all the configuration steps (as per this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UjP_TJOY5E&t=642s), however, when I go to run the app in Chrome, I get the following error. [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipo0j.png).

I have imported all the relevant amplify packages:

```
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:amplify_datastore/amplify_datastore.dart';
```

And this is my configuration function:

```
void _configureAmplify() {
    final provider = ModelProvider();
    final dataStorePlugin = AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: provider);

    try {
    Amplify.addPlugin(dataStorePlugin);
    Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
    debugPrint('Amplify Configured');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('$e');
    }
  }
```

I have also tried running the app on an android emulator, but this does not work either.

Please let me know how I should approach fixing this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hello AWS Amplify Developer Advocate here. This is a relatively old video, did you follow the installation process over docs as well? Also can you share which version of the AWS Amplify libraries are you running and lastly share where do you call your _configureAmplify function as well?

Comment: Hello, yes I followed the process over docs (is this what you are referring to: https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/flutter/#option-1-watch-the-video-guide). In my pubspec.yaml file, these are the lines I have for the libraries:  
amplify_flutter: '<1.0.0'
amplify_datastore: '<1.0.0'
amplify_datastore_plugin_interface: '<1.0.0'
I am calling my _configureamplify function from the initstate method for the page. Hmm, I'm wondering if I need to call it from the main.dart instead of one of the pages.

Comment: As per the Web support, it starts of from 1.0.0.next version. It is on Developer Preview. Can you update the libraries to use it to do the following --> 

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/flutter/#set-up-your-application

Comment: I would recommend going through the Getting Started page that I shared step by step with a brand new project which uses a Flutter version of 3.0 or higher.

Comment: Ok, I have updated all of them to be ^0.6.0, my application doesn't seem to have a podfile within the ios folder for some reason, is this an issue? Also, should I be calling the configureamplify function from the main.dart file or can that be called from anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: When you run your project on iOS it should generate the podfile for you for the first time. About the main.dart, I can recommend a way. Let me add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I also made this video to help you out --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooCc5wdVyMo

Addition to our discussions on the comment section. I recommend calling the `_configureAmplify` function from the main function. You can call it like the following:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await _configureAmplify();
  runApp(const AmplifyGroceryListApp());
}
    
Future<void> _configureAmplify() async {
  // Add the following lines to your app initialization to add the DataStore plugin
  final datastorePlugin = AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: ModelProvider.instance);
  await Amplify.addPlugin(datastorePlugin);
  try {
    await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
  } on AmplifyAlreadyConfiguredException {
    safePrint(
        'Tried to reconfigure Amplify; this can occur when your app restarts on Android.');
  }
}
```